# DOI name validation with pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm trying to understand how to use [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) for data parsing & validation.

The idea I had in mind was following:

- I have a list of DOI names for which I need to collect metadata
- I could use `pydantic` to test if the DOI name is valid

  - if it's valid, I proceed with making a request to *scite* api
  - if not, the code raises an exception instead of calling api

Very basic idea as you see.

---

The code:

*scite_utils.py*

```py
import requests
from ratelimit import limits, sleep_and_retry
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, constr


class DOI(BaseModel):
    name: constr(regex=r"^10\.\d{4,9}/[-._;()/:a-zA-Z0-9]+$")


@sleep_and_retry
@limits(calls=40, period=60) # api ratelimits
def remote_call(endpoint: str):
    r = requests.get(f"https://api.scite.ai/{endpoint}")
    r.encoding = "UTF-8"
    return r.json() 


def get_paper(doi: DOI):
    if not isinstance(doi, DOI):
        try:
            doi = DOI(name=doi).name
        except ValidationError:
            return 
    return remote_call(endpoint=f"papers/{doi}")
```

---

*test.py*

```py
import pandas as pd
from typing import List
from scite_utils import DOI, get_paper


# a sample of 5 but realisticlly - thousands?
DOIs = [
    "10.12724/ajss.47.0", 
    "10.31124/advance.12630065.v1", 
    "obv_error",
    "10.1122ajss.123.9",
    "10.1080/09662830500528294"
]


def create_table(names: List[DOI]):
    data = [get_paper(name) for name in names]
    return pd.DataFrame(
        publication 
        for publication in data
        if publication is not None
    )

if __name__=="__main__":
    result = create_table(DOIs)
    print(result)
```

---

Questions:

1. Is this a valid use case for `pydantic`?
2. Should I validate DOI name inside of the function that makes a request
   (or is there a better place for it, like a separate function)?
3. Doesn't it look awkward generally? I feel like I'm missing the point,
   because I could've written a custom function with `re` to validate DOI name.